# Install gtk, webkit and jswebkit with python

Tags: python, webkit

I need the following modules for python:

```
import gtk
import webkit
import jswebkit
```

Anyone who knows where to find them and how to install them on Mac and/or ubuntu? I got gtk running, cause when I run `python import gtk`in the terminal, I don't receive any errors. Can't get webkit and jswebkit installed, anyone who knows how to get this done?

Comment: Did you checked at `https://pypi.python.org`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job, *(it certainly does on Ubuntu)*:

```
sudo apt-get install python-jswebkit
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 python-webkit
```